# Display WPF Form on top of another third party full screen application?

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, fullscreen, wpf-4.0

I have a regular WPF windows form that I would like to display on-top of another running full screen application without the full screen application minimizing and the windows task bar showing up. The other application is in full screen mode like how a game is when in full screen mode.

From what I understand setting Top Most only works when there is no application in a true full screen mode.  My form is NOT a full screen window, it is just a small form I would like running and displaying on top of the other full screen application.

How can this be done using .net [I am fine with window invokes if needed]?

As an added note, if what is above is possible, what would happen when the user clicks on my form, would it cause the other full screen application to minimize [as I do not want that to happen] or cause the windows task bar to show up?

THANKS!

Comment: Winforms and WFP are two different display APIs; which one do you mean? Or are you hosting one inside the other? If so, which is being hosted inside what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

and on Loaded event
SetForegroundWindow(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);

Let me know if it works